# Fullcalendar prev /next API

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have implemented the fullcaleandar in angular and it is working fine. Usually the prev / next click will update the month/day/week views based on which tab is currently active. But I have custom buttons to increment or decrement week and day values. So I am trying to update the month alone in the fullcalendar prev and next buttons irrespective of the active view tab. ( only because I have other buttons to control the day/week views)

That means even if the calendar is in day/week view, if I am clicking the Fullcalendar next/prev buttons, the month value should increment/decrement -- not the day/week value.

Iam thinking about any option to send month data to the inbuild calendar api which is triggered  while calling prev/next ?  Is it possible to do so as per fullcalendar methods ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If you're in month view, then clicking the next or previous buttons (or running the [equivalent functions](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-navigation) will navigate forward or back by one month. If you're in week view, the same buttons (or functions) will navigate by one week. If you're in day view, they navigate by one day. That all makes sense. It's unclear to me what you're trying to customise or why? What exact different thing do you want to happen when clicking those buttons? Maybe you just need to re-word your question a bit.

Comment: @ADyson I have updated the question, please check whether its clear now. I want to update the month view on clicking those icons. Now as per fullcalendar, all the three views are updating with same buttons right ? I have included other 2 buttons for week and day views. so I just want these buttons to increment / decrement the month data alone. Hope its clear.  That is , say for example,If calendar is in june, and day tab, if iam clicking next button, the month should move to July, irrespective of the active view.

Comment: I see, yes that's clearer. Just one question - if it's in "day" mode, for example, and the day is 10th June, when the "next month" button is pressed, should the calendar move to 1st July, or 10th July? There exists a "next year" button fullCalendar already which, in the example I've just given would take the calendar to 10th June the following year, so I guess for consistency it should behave the same way for yours, and go to 10th July, but I just wanted to check your intention?

Comment: My intention was  to shift to july 1 st..  In the method you are specifying, can we shift to july 10 2021 with fullcalendar ? If we use nextyear it will be shifted to july10 2022 right , if the day id 2021 june 10? I am not sure , just asking ...

Comment: The nextYear method only goes to the next year. You can't use that for your idea, it was just mentioned for comparison. I was asking what you wanted such a method to do so that we can create one. If you create a custom button, then when it runs you can get the current date, extract the month from it, increment that by one and then use the goToDate function (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-gotoDate) to go to the 1st of the next month

Comment: okay,I was trying whether any option available with fulcalendar.  if no option available to input data to fullcalendar inbuild api, i will try with custom button. Thanks@ADyson.

Comment: No problem. If you get stuck with your attempt, please update your question with the code I can assist you with getting it fully correct. But if you find the solution please add it as an Answer below, so we can all benefit - thanks :-)

Answer (score -1):

It is actually **not possible** until you try rewriting some part of FullCalendar Code. The [Fullcalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs) suggests that increment and decrement depends on the current view. Ideally, the use case (even the API provided by FullCalendar) suggests that, If month is the view then, 1 month is incremented. If is a week view, 1 week in incremented. You may try finding some workarounds but, I don't think there are any.

One suggested workaround is to:

- Get the current date FullCalendar is displaying
- Get the current View ('timeGridDay', etc.)
- Then use the [changeView method](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-changeView) by incrementing the `dateOrRange` object